# In the "Subtlety Optional" assassination, what counts as a muscle car?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

In the assassination "Subtlety Optional" assassination given by Angel, he says to pull up to a certain gas station in a muscle car to lure out the owner/target.  I have tried several different cars like the Vortex and Raycaster, but none of them seem to be what he's looking for.  Admittedly, those are more sports cars than muscle cars, but I'm not sure I've come across any actual muscle cars.

What cars can I actually use to complete this mission and where can I find them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a very short list - I think maybe 4 total:

- [Bootlegger](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Bootlegger)
- [Hammerhead](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Hammerhead)
- [Phoenix](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Phoenix)
- [Hammer](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Hammer) (this one definitely works)

They're tricky to spot, and they're *not* sports cars (so the Torch/Temptress/etc don't count).

I found they tend to spawn outside the Angel's Gym crib the most often, in the parking lot and surrounding lots.

I believe the Bootlegger is also a possible gang vehicle option, if you select it from the gang customization menu at one of your hideouts.  However, you'll have to figure out a way to make your homies show up if you go this route.  There's an upgrade option in the phone which gives you the ability to call some gang members, which is the most reliable way.

I think the Phoenix is driven by a particular homie (possible spoiler if you've not advanced the plot to the point where you meet the Mayor):

> Mayor Reynolds - he drives a Phoenix customized to look like the Trans Am he drives in [Smokey and the Bandit](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076729/)

Comment: I was so relieved when I found out that the homie's car could be used there.  I had a tough time trying to remember where I saw the muscle cars in the city and was not looking forward to searching around.  Fortunately I had his/her number.

Comment: I'll wait until I get this homie to finish the quest, then.  It sounds much easier than finding one around the city.  Thanks!

Comment: @DaveMcClelland, you'll be given a choice about that particular homie - so he's kind of missable (although honestly, I don't know why you wouldn't take him, I mean *come on!*)  The gang customization method is pretty easy and available early, though.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this: **Call Josh Birk** as a homie. He'll arrive in a Bootlegger muscle car.

Note: **Not** the Nyteblade homie, which is different.