# How might I find the Hammerhead?

Tags: pc, saints-row-the-third, saints-row-iv

In the Saints Row series, there exists a muscle car called the [Hammerhead](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/Hammerhead). The Saints Row Wiki does not contain any information on locating the vehicle in Saints Row: The Third and Saints Row IV, and I'm really wanting to find it in the PC versions of these games. Could I get a nudge in the right direction in terms of getting myself a Hammerhead [without the use of cheats] in both games?

Comment: I get the feeling that it's like http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/96455/46216 .

Comment: Related: [In the “Subtlety Optional” assassination, what counts as a muscle car?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/41553/4797)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, But it's purely luck. There is no way to spawn it using console commands and there is no set spawn. The best thing to do is go around the map until you find it. Hope this helps.